# How to transfer data from MYsql server to iphone

Tags: iphone, mysql, sqlite

I created a webservice in RDB with .Net.I able to transfer data from iphone to mysql and it returns the data.

But i need to transfer data from RDB to iphone whenever i need
(i am strucked by the ip address of iphone which one is dynamic to connect the device from a RDB)

Please tell me how i will do it otherwise tell is any other way.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This has been asked 100 times

Answer (score 0):

Pushing information to the phone probably will involve some socket programming on the iphone, i havent tried doing this so i cant be of much help there, another alternative is using a pull model, where you can have the iphone poll your webservice every so often to check for changes, that way you can also ensure the app is up to date with the database, i used this model to implement a small chat service on the iphone, it works pretty well..

Answer (score 0):

You could either pull, or have the app register for push notifications when active and be told when updates are available (you can opt to receive notifications only when the app is open, notification data packets are not large enough to hold the data updates themselves).